# execute a function from js file in vue component every time mounted in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

I have a project in drf and vuejs. for the frontend, I used a created theme that has some static css files and js files.
in a js file named chart.js, I have this code to create some charts on a specific component named chart.vue.
this is my chart.js:

```
!function (t) {
var e = {};

function r(o) {
    if (e[o]) return e[o].exports;
    var n = e[o] = {i: o, l: !1, exports: {}};
    return t[o].call(n.exports, n, n.exports, r), n.l = !0, n.exports
}

r.m = t, r.c = e, r.d = function (t, e, o) {
    r.o(t, e) || Object.defineProperty(t, e, {enumerable: !0, get: o})
}, r.r = function (t) {
    "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(t, Symbol.toStringTag, {value: "Module"}), Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {value: !0})
}, r.t = function (t, e) {
    if (1 & e && (t = r(t)), 8 & e) return t;
    if (4 & e && "object" == typeof t && t && t.__esModule) return t;
    var o = Object.create(null);
    if (r.r(o), Object.defineProperty(o, "default", {
        enumerable: !0,
        value: t
    }), 2 & e && "string" != typeof t) for (var n in t) r.d(o, n, function (e) {
        return t[e]
    }.bind(null, n));
    return o
}, r.n = function (t) {
    var e = t && t.__esModule ? function () {
        return t.default
    } : function () {
        return t
    };
    return r.d(e, "a", e), e
}, r.o = function (t, e) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, e)
}, r.p = "/", r(r.s = 53)}({53: function (t, e, r) {
    t.exports = r(54)
}, 54: function (t, e) {
    $((function (t) {
        "use strict";
        (e = $("#btc-market")).height(50);
        new Chart(e, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                labels: ["شهریور","مرداد","تیر","خرداد","اردیبهشت","فروردین","اسفند","بهمن","دی","آذر","آبان","مهر"],
                type: "line",
                datasets: [{
                    data: [85, 75, 96, 84, 85, 92, 79, 78, 74, 85, 86, 80],
                    label: "قیمت اتریوم",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(98, 89, 202, 0.2)",
                    borderColor: "#6259ca",
                    borderWidth: "2",
                    pointBorderColor: "transparent",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
                }]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: !1,
                legend: {display: !1},
                responsive: !0,
                tooltips: {
                    mode: "index",
                    titleFontSize: 12,
                    titleFontColor: "#7886a0",
                    bodyFontColor: "#7886a0",
                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                    titleFontFamily: "iransans",
                    bodyFontFamily: "iransans",
                    cornerRadius: 3,
                    intersect: !1
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {color: "transparent", zeroLineColor: "transparent"},
                        ticks: {fontSize: 2, fontColor: "transparent"}
                    }], yAxes: [{display: !1, ticks: {display: !1}}]
                },
                title: {display: !1},
                elements: {line: {borderWidth: 1}, point: {radius: 4, hitRadius: 10, hoverRadius: 4}}
            }
        });
        (e = $("#ethereum-market")).height(50);
        new Chart(e, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                labels: ["شهریور","مرداد","تیر","خرداد","اردیبهشت","فروردین","اسفند","بهمن","دی","آذر","آبان","مهر"],
                type: "line",
                datasets: [{
                    data: [34, 23, 54, 34, 56, 76, 34, 76, 34, 55, 23, 76],
                    label: "قیمت اتریوم",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(98, 89, 202, 0.2)",
                    borderColor: "#6259ca",
                    borderWidth: "2",
                    pointBorderColor: "transparent",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
                }]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: !1,
                legend: {display: !1},
                responsive: !0,
                tooltips: {
                    mode: "index",
                    titleFontSize: 12,
                    titleFontColor: "#7886a0",
                    bodyFontColor: "#7886a0",
                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                    titleFontFamily: "iransans",
                    bodyFontFamily: "iransans",
                    cornerRadius: 3,
                    intersect: !1
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {color: "transparent", zeroLineColor: "transparent"},
                        ticks: {fontSize: 2, fontColor: "transparent"}
                    }], yAxes: [{display: !1, ticks: {display: !1}}]
                },
                title: {display: !1},
                elements: {line: {borderWidth: 1}, point: {radius: 4, hitRadius: 10, hoverRadius: 4}}
            }
        });
        (e = $("#xrp-market")).height(50);
        var e;
        new Chart(e, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                labels: ["شهریور","مرداد","تیر","خرداد","اردیبهشت","فروردین","اسفند","بهمن","دی","آذر","آبان","مهر"],
                type: "line",
                datasets: [{
                    data: [7, 5, 7, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 9, 6, 5, 9, 7, 3, 5, 2, 7, 10],
                    label: "قیمت اتریوم",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(98, 89, 202, 0.2)",
                    borderColor: "#6259ca",
                    borderWidth: "2",
                    pointBorderColor: "transparent",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
                }]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: !1,
                legend: {display: !1},
                responsive: !0,
                tooltips: {
                    mode: "index",
                    titleFontSize: 12,
                    titleFontColor: "#7886a0",
                    bodyFontColor: "#7886a0",
                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                    titleFontFamily: "iransans",
                    bodyFontFamily: "iransans",
                    cornerRadius: 3,
                    intersect: !1
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {color: "transparent", zeroLineColor: "transparent"},
                        ticks: {fontSize: 2, fontColor: "transparent"}
                    }], yAxes: [{display: !1, ticks: {display: !1}}]
                },
                title: {display: !1},
                elements: {line: {borderWidth: 1}, point: {radius: 4, hitRadius: 10, hoverRadius: 4}}
            }
        });
        (e = $("#ltc-market")).height(50);
        new Chart(e, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                labels: ["شهریور","مرداد","تیر","خرداد","اردیبهشت","فروردین","اسفند","بهمن","دی","آذر","آبان","مهر"],
                type: "line",
                datasets: [{
                    data: [15, 6, 16, 11, 12, 15, 10, 19, 16, 13, 12, 15, 7, 16, 11],
                    label: "قیمت اتریوم",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(98, 89, 202, 0.2)",
                    borderColor: "#6259ca",
                    borderWidth: "2",
                    pointBorderColor: "transparent",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
                }]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: !1,
                legend: {display: !1},
                responsive: !0,
                tooltips: {
                    mode: "index",
                    titleFontSize: 12,
                    titleFontColor: "#7886a0",
                    bodyFontColor: "#7886a0",
                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                    titleFontFamily: "iransans",
                    bodyFontFamily: "iransans",
                    cornerRadius: 3,
                    intersect: !1
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {color: "transparent", zeroLineColor: "transparent"},
                        ticks: {fontSize: 2, fontColor: "transparent"}
                    }], yAxes: [{display: !1, ticks: {display: !1}}]
                },
                title: {display: !1},
                elements: {line: {borderWidth: 1}, point: {radius: 4, hitRadius: 10, hoverRadius: 4}}
            }
        })
    }))
}});
```

I load the js file to my component like a blow.
this is my chart.vue component:

```
<template><!-- row -->
    <div class="row row-sm">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-4 col-md-6 col-12">
        <div class="card custom-card">
          <div class="card-body pb-3">
            <h5 class="tx-14">BTC / USD</h5>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <div class="">
                <h4 class="mb-2">34.4324 <span class="text-muted tx-12">29.42 تومان</span></h4>
                <div class="d-flex text-muted tx-13"><span class="text-danger ml-2 font-weight-bold">-0.22٪</span>
                  حجم - 76،434.57 USDT
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex mr-auto float-right">
                <canvas id="btc-market" class="wd-50p wd-100-f mr-auto float-right"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-4 col-md-6 col-12">
        <div class="card custom-card">
          <div class="card-body pb-3">
            <h5 class="tx-14">ETH / USD</h5>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <div class="">
                <h4 class="mb-2">29.4124 <span class="text-muted tx-12">23.15 تومان</span></h4>
                <div class="d-flex text-muted tx-13"><span class="text-success ml-2 font-weight-bold">+ 0.23٪</span>
                  حجم - 23،346.56 USDT
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex mr-auto float-right">
                <canvas id="ethereum-market" class="wd-50p wd-100-f mr-auto float-right"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-4 col-md-6 col-12">
        <div class="card custom-card">
          <div class="card-body pb-3">
            <h5 class="tx-14">XRP / USD</h5>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <div class="">
                <h4 class="mb-2">34.5674 45.24 <span class="text-muted tx-12">تومان</span></h4>
                <div class="d-flex text-muted tx-13"><span class="text-danger ml-2 font-weight-bold"></span>-0.42
                  <span class="text-danger ml-2 font-weight-bold">٪</span> حجم - 56،456.12 USDT
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex mr-auto float-right">
                <canvas id="xrp-market" class="wd-50p wd-100-f mr-auto float-right"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End row -->
</template>
<script>
let effect = require('address to chart.js')
export default {
  name: "Chart",
}
</script>
```

the problem I have is when I open my component its works perfectly and showing my chart but when I change the route to another component and back to this component, the chart not showing. if I refresh the page manually it will show again perfectly.

this problem is on all effects I have like modal effect, etc.

I think you should know that I use vue.router for this project and this component have his own route.

Comment: You haven't included enough information to help

Comment: If you want to run a piece of code multiple times, export a function from a module and don't use IIFE. A module runs only once.

Comment: @EstusFlask so can you help me with how I do that?

Comment: try giving a name to the function and then in you mounted hook run `window.yourfucn()`

Comment: can you show me some example code? @aks